# C# Web App adding data twice to database

Tags: c#, web

I've tried a few things I've read on StackOverflow with some other topics with no success.

```
public partial class Content_Management : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

//Code fires EVERY TIME a Row is selected in the Gridview control
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Extract upload Title and assign to relevant Textbox control
    TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString();


    //Extract upload album name and assign to relevant Textbox control
    TextBox3.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.ToString();

    //Extract upload Image and assign to relevant Image control
    Image4.ImageUrl = "~/uploadedimages/" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString();

    //Extract upload Status and assign to DropDownList control
    DropDownList1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text.ToString();

    //Enable the "Update" Button control
    Button2.Enabled = true;

    //Extract upload Multimedia Clip and load into MediaPlayer control ready for playing
    Media_Player_Control1.MovieURL = Server.MapPath("~/uploaded_multimedia/" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString());
}

//This code will execute EVERY TIME "Save" Button is clicked
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Birdspotting"].ConnectionString);
    //Then I would reference the string e.g 
    //Create variable to point to image upload folder 

    string image_folder = Server.MapPath("~\\uploadedimages\\");

    //Create 2 variables and set the file names to blank in case User does not upload any files - DB entries will still be made
    string dbfilename1 = "";
    string dbfilename2 = "";

    //Check if the Image Fileupload control has a file or not
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        //If the Fileupload control has a file, change the value of the variable to the selected image file name
        string filename1 = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();

        //Copy the selected Image file from the Users device accross the Internet and save it into the Image folder within the Web App structure
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(image_folder + filename1);

        //Assign the new file name to the variable used to populate the DB - change from "" to actual file name
        dbfilename1 = filename1;
    }

    //Repeat as above for Multimedia Clip - audio or video
    string multimedia_folder = Server.MapPath("~\\uploaded_multimedia\\");
    if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
    {
        string filename2 = FileUpload2.FileName.ToString();
        FileUpload2.SaveAs(multimedia_folder + filename2);
        dbfilename2 = filename2;
    }

    //Create DB Connection - point to SQL 
    // create sql connection object. make sure to put a valid connection string
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into LeagueTable" + "(BirdName, Quantity, ArtworkImage, MediaClip, Username, Datetime, ActiveStatus, UserId)"
  + "Values(@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8) Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()");

    //SqlXml newXml = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader("Birds.xml"));
   using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        //Define the structure of the SQL Statement - used to executed instructions against the DB Table
        //The DB Table name and each field is indentified in the command.
        //INSERT commands includes Primary Key insertion -that is generated by the DB itself
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox1.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", TextBox3.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", dbfilename1.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", dbfilename2.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", User.Identity.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", DropDownList1.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            var added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblConfirm.Text = added.ToString() + "Record Inserted.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error Inserting Record";
            lblError.Text += ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me the button control that's on your page too please

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the top of the Button1_Click method. Does it get called once or twice ? Is the timestamp for both inserts exactly the same ?

Comment: @marwijn - It's calling just the once.

Comment: Can you show us the table data before and after the insertion? Also are you able to check through debugging what exactly is the sql query executed?